# module schedule/tracking does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: javascript, react-native

React Native Environment Info:

```
System:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
  CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7100 CPU @ 3.90GHz
  Memory: 559.26 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 10.11.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
  npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 12.0, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.0, watchOS 5.0
IDEs:
  Xcode: 10.0/10A255 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  react: 16.0.0 => 16.0.0 
  react-native: ^0.57.3 => 0.57.3 
npmGlobalPackages:
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

here is react-native info 
similar solutions from GitHub does not work for me

Answer (score 15):

The error appears due to the renaming of `schedule/tracking` to `schedule/tracing` from `react@16.5.1` to `react@16.5.2`.

The issue is resolved by choosing the correct version of `react` for your `react-native` version:

- **RN <= 0.57.2 --> react <= 16.5.1**

  - Be sure to lock your react version in this case. Your package.json should look like this: `react@16.5.1`. Check that there isn't any `^` before the version.
  - (having `react@^16.5.1` in your package.json may resolve to a react version >= 16.5.1, which will NOT work)
  - example command: `yarn add react@16.5.1`
- **RN >= 0.57.3 --> react >= 16.6**

  - example command: `yarn add react@16.6.0`

For further Information you can check the [Github Issue #21150](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21150) and [Github Issue #21140](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21140).

**Sidenote for Expo Users:**

If you are using expo, be aware that expo <= 32.0.0 uses a react-native version <=  0.57.2 and therefore will require the react version to be <= 16.5.1

**If it does not work immediately**

Try to reset the cache of your packager before continuing: `yarn start --reset-cache`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the version when using expo!

Answer (score 2):

If running with your versions of npm packages:

```
react: 16.0.0 => 16.0.0 
react-native: ^0.57.3 => 0.57.3
```

We'll have the same error as below:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `scheduler/tracing` from 
`C:\projects\rnw\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer- 
dev.js`: Module `scheduler/tracing` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

Upgrade to the following versions:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.6.3",
  "react-native": "0.58.1"
},
```

And the error will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an error related to module Schedule/tracking not found, use react-native 0.55.0 version. Above RN->0.55.0 version schedule/tracking package is renamed or moved to another module which is not found by node server.

Command: react-native init (Project Name) --version 0.55.0