# Duplicate module name: react

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, jsx, expo

I have a `react-native` project with the following `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "react-native-paper-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Example for React Native Paper",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "flow": "flow",
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo android",
    "ios": "expo ios"
  },
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "create-react-context": "^0.2.3",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "expo-core": "^2.0.0",
    "expo-font": "^2.0.0",
    "query-string": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "16.7.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.0.5",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^2.3.8",
    "flow-bin": "^0.91.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "**/create-react-context": "0.2.3",
    "**/hoist-non-react-statics": "2.5.0",
    "**/react-lifecycles-compat": "3.0.4",
    "**/react": "16.5.0"
  }
}
```

To install the modules I ran:

```
$ yarn install
```

**My problem is** that when I run:

```
$ expo start
```

I get the following errors:

```
[02:30:45] Your app is running at exp://192.168.1.194:19000
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
[02:30:56] (node:6184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
[02:30:56]   Duplicate module name: react
[02:30:56]   Paths: D:\react-native-app\node_modules\create-react-context\node_modules\react\package.json collides with D:\react-native-app\node_modules\react\package.json
[02:30:56]
[02:30:56] This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
[02:30:56]     at setModule (D:\react-native-app\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:462:17)
[02:30:56]     at workerReply (D:\react-native-app\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:512:9)
[02:30:56]     at <anonymous>
[02:30:56]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
[02:30:56] (node:6184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
[02:30:56] (node:6184) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove this line `"**/react": "16.5.0"` from your resolutions, because it is incompatible with the react version you specified as dependency: `"react": "16.7.0",`

Comment: after removing that resolution, removed directory: `node_modules` and done again: `$ yarn install`, I did: `$ expo start` and got the following error: `Unable to resolve "schedule/tracking" from "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js"`. Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be related to the name change of schedule/tracking to schedule/tracing in react. You got two options:
1. update your version of react-native
2. downgrade react to 16.5.1 with `yarn add react@16.5.1`

Comment: I like the idea of update/upgrade things. So, what do I have to do in order to take the update option?

Comment: This is the harder way to go, because the bug is already fixed in RN 0.57.3 but apparently expos sdk v32.0.0 is based on a RN 0.57.x version < 0.57.3
You could try to update to [expo version 32.0.1](https://github.com/expo/react-native/releases/tag/sdk-32.0.1) and hope that the fix is merged there.
The RN 0.57 version which is the base for expo 32.0.0 locked react strictly 16.5.0 because of this. I would recommend to downgrade react to 16.5.1 and upgrade it accordingly to your RN and expo version and not the other way around.

Comment: You can also check out my [stackoverflow answer to similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54427170/7381594).