# module schedule does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scheduler

***Intro***

Hello to all, I read similar questions about this frequent problem, but I wasn't able to solve it.

[First question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817118/module-schedule-tracking-does-not-exist-in-the-haste-module-map)

[GitHub post](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21150)

***What did I try ?***

I tried to follow the first link, but nothing happen, tried to reinstall scheduler at 0.4.0 version. but nothing, the problem still persists. 
When I run the app I view in the IOS emulator of Xcode the word " TEST " for a bunch of seconds, and than it crashes.

***Json Package***

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.15.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.0",
    "schedule": "0.4.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

***Expected Behaviour***

Not have this crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have schedule in your package.json as dependency. This shouldn't be necessary as it is part of react: https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/scheduler

I would suggest to remove it (`yarn remove schedule`) or at least upgrade to version 0.5.0 (`yarn add --dev schedule@0.5.0`) for compatibility with the react version.

Make sure to reset the cache of your packager afterwards: `yarn start --reset-cache`