# Module `scheduler/tracing` does not exist in the Haste module map Error in react-native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am New to react-native i have created a new project in react-native but I am getting this error shown below I have tried to remove and re-add node modules in project but it still didn't solved this problem

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `scheduler/tracing` from `C:\Users\user\Desktop\MediaPlayer\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js`: Module `scheduler/tracing` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MediaPlayer\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:183:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MediaPlayer\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MediaPlayer\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:283:16)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MediaPlayer\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42)
    at dependencies.map.result (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MediaPlayer\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:399:31)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MediaPlayer\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:18)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\MediaPlayer\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:269:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\user\Desktop\MediaPlayer\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
 DELTA  [android, dev] ..\..\../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░ 56.7% (284/377), failed.

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [05/Jun/2019:17:37:23 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
```

Environment info

```
 React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10
      CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4310U CPU @ 2.00GHz
      Memory: 1.58 GB / 7.91 GB
    Binaries:
      npm: 6.4.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  3.1.0.0 AI-173.4819257

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.9
```

Comment: What is your react version? Issues like this are usually the result of the renaming of the module `schdule/trac(k)ing module`. Please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54427170/7381594

Answer (score 0):

yarn start --reset-cache

remove node module and re install

yarn or npm i